# Get Age from Date of Birth

Tags: datetime

I have an entry with a dateOfBirth Date/Time Field.

Is it possible to calculate the current age from that field?

I can't find a craft/twig function/filter to calculate the difference between 2 dates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Craft's Date/Time field extends PHP's DateTime class so (since 5.3.0) you can use the [Diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method like so:

```
yourDateTimeField.diff(now).format('%y')
```